# Show a ContextMenuStrip without it showing in the taskbar

Tags: .net, c++, winforms

I have found that when I execute the show() method for a contextmenustrip (a right click menu), if the position is outside that of the form it belongs to, it shows up on the taskbar also.

I am trying to create a right click menu for when clicking on the notifyicon, but as the menu hovers above the system tray and not inside the form (as the form can be minimised when right clicking) it shows up on the task bar for some odd reason

Here is my code currently:

```
private: System::Void notifyIcon1_MouseClick(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e) {

if(e->Button == System::Windows::Forms::MouseButtons::Right) {

        this->sysTrayMenu->Show(Cursor->Position);

    }
}
```

What other options do I need to set so it doesn't show up a blank process on the task bar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try assigning your menu to the ContextMenuStrip property of NotifyIcon rather than showing it in the mouse click handler.

Comment: Ah! You're a genius!  I had no idea that they had a property for this!  I was doing things the 'hard' way again :)

Comment: Lots of other controls have this property, too.

Comment: I think this will solve it for me too, but I am kinda new to all this. Could somebody explain how I would "assign" the menu to the ContextMenuStrip? I think it is rather obvious once I've seen it, but for now I don't have a clue :)

Comment: Never mind, I found out how to do it. For others who come along this problem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.contextmenu(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 7):

The best and right way, without Reflection is:

```
{
  UnsafeNativeMethods.SetForegroundWindow(new HandleRef(notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip, notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip.Handle));
  notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip.Show(Cursor.Position);
}
```

where **UnsafeNativeMethods.SetForegroundWindow** is:

```
public static class UnsafeNativeMethods
{
  [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
  public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(HandleRef hWnd);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to show a different ContextMenuStrip for left and right mouse button, but whitout SetForegroundWindow, the ContextMenuStrip creates an ugly icon in the taskbar, and the focus of that ContextMenuStrip didn't work pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that you have 2 context menu items: `ContextMenuLeft` and `ContextMenuRight`. By default, from the NotifyIcon properties you already assigned one of them. Before calling `Left Button Click`, just change them, show the context menu, and then change them again.

```
NotifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip = ContextMenuLeft; //let's asign the other one
MethodInfo mi = typeof(NotifyIcon).GetMethod("ShowContextMenu", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
mi.Invoke(NotifyIcon, null);
NotifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip = ContextMenuRight; //switch back to the default one
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I have is that my menu is available from both a double middle-click *and* the notification icon.

When right clicking the notification icon, there is no taskbar button, but when I manually Show(Cursor.Position) then it shows a taskbar button.