# Checking the visibility of a ContextMenu when associated with a NotifyIcon

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4680819/2) on another question, the `Collapsed` event of a ContextMenu is only raised if it's associated to a control before calling `Show()`.

SInce a `NotifyIcon` does not count as a control, I can't hook onto the `Collapsed` event to detect when the menu associated to one is hidden.

Are there any workarounds?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invoke NotifyIcon's Context Menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208690/invoke-notifyicons-context-menu)

Comment: Question is asking how to check visibility of a ContextMenu, not how to display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the "Remarks" section for the MSDN docs on [TrackPopupMenuEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648003%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), it says:

> To display a context menu for a notification icon, the current window
>   must be the foreground window before the application calls
>   TrackPopupMenu or TrackPopupMenuEx. Otherwise, the menu will not
>   disappear when the user clicks outside of the menu or the window that
>   created the menu (if it is visible). If the current window is a child
>   window, you must set the (top-level) parent window as the foreground
>   window.

So that could mean that when the `ContextMenu` is visible, the window on the `NotifyIcon` will be the foreground window. You can see from by looking at `NotifyIcon.ShowContextMenu()` that it is indeed the case:

```
    private void ShowContextMenu()
    {
        if (this.contextMenu != null || this.contextMenuStrip != null)
        {
            NativeMethods.POINT pOINT = new NativeMethods.POINT();
            UnsafeNativeMethods.GetCursorPos(pOINT);
            UnsafeNativeMethods.SetForegroundWindow(new HandleRef(this.window, this.window.Handle));
            if (this.contextMenu != null)
            {
                this.contextMenu.OnPopup(EventArgs.Empty);
                SafeNativeMethods.TrackPopupMenuEx(new HandleRef(this.contextMenu, this.contextMenu.Handle), 72, pOINT.x, pOINT.y, new HandleRef(this.window, this.window.Handle), null);
                UnsafeNativeMethods.PostMessage(new HandleRef(this.window, this.window.Handle), 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
                return;
            }
            if (this.contextMenuStrip != null)
            {
                this.contextMenuStrip.ShowInTaskbar(pOINT.x, pOINT.y);
            }
        }
    }
```

Using ILSpy I then noticed `NotifyIcon` has a private member `window`, which refers to a private class with base type `NativeWindow`. Therefore, you can check like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

...

FieldInfo notifyIconNativeWindowInfo = typeof(NotifyIcon).GetField("window", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
NativeWindow notifyIconNativeWindow = (NativeWindow)notifyIconNativeWindowInfo.GetValue(notifyIcon1);

bool visible = notifyIcon1.Handle == GetForegroundWindow();
```