# NotifyIcon does not disappear after losing focus

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a form which have a NotifyIcon. The form is hiden by default, but the NotifyIcon is visible in the system tray. My question/problem is that when I clicking on the Icon and then clicking away the NotifyIcon's ContextMenuStrip element does not disappearing. 
I tried LostFocus event, but it does not fires if I click outside of the application.

Is there any solution for this problem?
Thank you for the answers in advance!

Code I used:

```
Private Sub NotifyIcon1_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles NotifyIcon1.MouseClick
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
        ContextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub History_LostFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.LostFocus, ContextMenuStrip1.LostFocus
    ContextMenuStrip1.Hide()
End Sub
```

Comment: Would you please share the code you used to get the above behavior? Without the code, it could be the issue specific to your implementation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invoke NotifyIcon's Context Menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208690/invoke-notifyicons-context-menu)

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to check the thread you mentioned.

Comment: It does not solved the problem, however I added an else to the if to hide it if not right mousebutton used.