# How to determine if user clicks out of ContextMenuStrip?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am building winform application without any form shown (opacity of form is 0 and ShowInTaskbar property is false). It is accessible only from tray Notify icon. When users clicks with left mouse button on it, the contextMenustrip menu will be show. Because I want to detect LEFT mouse button click I can't use ContextMenu Property of NotifyIcon.

I would like, that if users clicks whenever out of the menu, it should hide. I don't have any idea how I can do that...

If I have shown form, I could detect Deactivate form event and then hide my menu, but in described situation it looks harder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invoke NotifyIcon's Context Menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208690/invoke-notifyicons-context-menu)

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you. I couldn't find suitable topic. It works.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you. I couldn't find suitable topic. It works. According to your advice I have used reflection to call ShowContextMenu() method in MouseUp event. What I did in different way is that I have two ContextMenuStrip menus: one connected with ContextMenuProperty of NFI and second, not connected with NIF. Invoking ShowContextMenu() with reflection and later manually showing unconnected menu resolves the problem, despite that I don't connect this menu in NIF ContextMenu property. Could you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

1) Instead of setting opacity to 0 better set `WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized`

2) You cant detect mouse clicks outside of your program as they are controlled by other programs or your OS, but handling `Leave` or `MouseLeave` event should help you